# Where did CCSpriteSheet go in Cocos2D version 1.0.1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Did they remove CCSpriteSheet in version 1.0.1 or did am I just missing it? if they removed it, is there something else that replaced it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been deprecated since at least 0.99.5. Use [CCSpriteBatchNode](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_sprite_batch_node.html) instead.